# Textbox validation in jquery disabling space

Tags: asp.net

How can I disable **space as first character** in the textbox in asp.net c# using jquery?

Comment: if you got the answer then please select your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `JQUERY` as below:

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").keypress(function(evt){
         var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
        if($(this).val().length==0){
            if(cc==32)
                 return false;
             }
    });

});
```

`a is the your textbox Id`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LUVQX/)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function validateTextBox()
{
    var txt = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
        if(txt.charAt(0)==' '){
           alert("No space allowed in the beginning");
           }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem isn't related to C#/asp.net. All u need is javascript.

just try to catch the onkeydown event.

```
$("#text").keydown(function(){
    var txt = $(this).value;
    if(txt.charAt(0)==' '){
       alert("No space in the beginning");
       txt.value(txt.replace(" ",""));//clear first space in text
     }
});
```

text is id of input